# context object not work in jsp or servlet file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating many jsp and servlet files but,This time I am confuse...

I have 1 servlet file called test.java

```
ServletContext context =  request.getServletContext();

context.setAttribute("Fname","chintan");
context.setAttribute("Lname","popat");
request.getRequestDispacher("test.jsp").forword(request,response);
```

in test.jsp

```
<%
   String fname = (String)context.getAttribute("Fname");  //popat
   String lname = (String)context.getAttribute("Lname");  //popat
%>
```

in jsp file get all context attribute value which store in last context object 
so how it can possible
2 diff attribute return sample value while i am set diff value

Comment: That's really weird. Should not happen.

Comment: Are you using a variable (overwriting) value in the set for the "chintan" and "popat" values ? I.E string value = "chintan" , context.setAttribute("Fname",value);

Comment: context is object of "ServletContext"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working test :

In servlet :

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("Fname","chintan");
context.setAttribute("Lname","popat");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

test.jsp :

```
<%
String fname = (String)application.getAttribute("Fname");  //chintan
String lname = (String)application.getAttribute("Lname");  //popat
out.write(fname); out.write(lname);
%>
```

writes correctly `chintanpopat`

But ... it works with one single request at same time because application context is shared between all requests of the application. And in a jsp the servlet context is accessible through `application` not `context` (unless you have set it elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong, use forward method from PageContext, not from RequestDispatcher

```
       pageContext.forward("/resource.jsp");
```

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jspapi/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#forward(java.lang.String)

Comment: There is same problem

Comment: Try request.setAttribute("attribute-name","attribute-value"). And get it from page as "${requestScope['attribute-name']}"